# How to parse mathematical notation for this combinatorial problem?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

So in the paper found here:

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01819761

We find this theorem
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaAKY.jpg)
. I was having difficulty parsing the actual notation they're using and want to program this algorithm. But I don't understand what that second summation is even doing. Is $j_i$ the first element of the set of values input to the function or does it start at one and sum to that term? What is $j_t$ or even $s_t$ going to be equal to at any step of that final product term? There's a lot going on here and it's hard to read.

Comment: This seems buggered up by the typesetters (or by the scanners). The formula makes no sense as stated. Perhaps the two summation signs should be understood (together) as a sum over all $\left(k-1\right)$-tuples $\left(j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_{k-1}\right)$ of integers with $1 \leq j_i \leq s_i$ for all $i$. Now, what in the nine circles is the $j_{k^{+1}-1}$ supposed to mean? No idea.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'm fairly confident they mean $j_{k+1}-1$ and I do agree that's an abysmal typesetting issue. I mean, even if I had two interpretations, I could code them both and work them with known values. I just need to know if there is at least one or two ways to read it. Sort of like a typographical Rorschach test if you will.

Comment: The problem is that there is no $j_{k+1}$. Maybe $j_{k-1}$ ?

Comment: Anyway, it might be better to use one of the simple recursions and dynamical programming than such a formula.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yeah, we're operating on a set of three elements and a recursive solution would probably be neater- I just already tried and failed to program those. I was mostly trying to get this formula down for personal use should a similar problem come up again.

Comment: Does this mean you're counting Carlitz words over a $3$-letter alphabet? This can be done much more easily: These correspond to walks in the complete graph $K_3$. And these can be obtained by taking powers of the adjacency matrix. Since you want only words with a given multiplicity of each letter, you need to put indeterminates instead of $1$s into the non-diagonal cells of the matrix. (The method works for any finite alphabet, but of course the matrix will grow larger the more letters it has.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg Whoa! Okay I definitely see the bijection from words to walks for the unconstrained case and that's super neat. Thank you. I'm still unclear what you mean about constraining the multiplicity in this fashion: Care to elaborate?

Comment: If you want to count only those Carlitz words that have each letter $i$ appear $m_i$ times, you won't want the whole sum of entries of a power of the matrix. Instead, you want to sneak variables into the matrix -- so that the sum of entries becomes a polynomial -- and then extract a coefficient of a specific monomial.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Okay, I'll try and hash out an algorithm. Thank you.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Can I put your name in the acknowledgements for my presentation and any papers that might come later in my research?

Comment: Sure you can (though it's not really necessary).